# Postman showing empty JSON object from spring boot rest api

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, postman

```
public class UserController {
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@GetMapping
public List<User> findAllUsers() {
    return (List<User>) userRepository.findAll();
}
```

}

This is the code of the controller class

Answer (score 0):

you specified the url in the `@RequestMapping("...")` annotation

```
@RequestMapping("url")
public class UserController {
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@GetMapping
public List<User> findAllUsers() {
    return (List<User>) userRepository.findAll();
}
```

and add the `@RestController` annotation above the class